# Priority of the content of a note by Lebesgue from 1905

Tags: reference-request, math-history

I refer to a note by Lebesgue [*Remarques sur la définition de l'intégrale*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k4862594/f234.image.langEN), Bull.Sci.Math. 29 (1905) 272-275 not very known (see [pdf](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.1412v1.pdf) for an exposition in English).

It is a pedagogical note containing a method of proving the existence of an antiderivative of a continuous function alternative to Cauchy-Riemann integration (or a way, among others, to introduce the Newton integral *Riemann-free*).

In the first part Lebesgue shows that a continuous function admits an antiderivative because it can be represented by a uniformly convergent sequence of piecewise linear functions and one knows that a uniformly convergent sequence of derivatives represents a derivative.

I doubt that such a thing was shown for the first time in 1905 ...

Do you know something about ?

Comment: One can find this approach in Kuratowski _Introduction to Calculus_, 1962 (polish edition 1946)

Comment: Several authors call antidifferentiation _Newton integration_.