# Is This Referring to the Existence of an Antiderivative?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

My text gave the following statement for the FTOC:

Let $f$ be an integrable function on $[a, b]$, $F$ be the antiderivative of $f$.
Then $$ \int_a^b f \, du = F(b) - F(a)$$
Why does the book need to specify that $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$? 
Is it suggesting that while $f$ is integrable, the derivative of the integral may not be $f$? 
I don't recall encountering such a situation in Calculus ....  TY

Comment: Well, because $\,F\,$ **must** be an antiderivative, or if you prefer a primitive function, of $\,f\,$...To talk about "the derivative of the integral" is, imo, a little confusing: the derivative wrt what of what integral?

Comment: Does it say that $F$ is *the* antiderivative, or does it say that $F$ is *an* antiderivative? The latter is correct, and is required because if $F$ is an antiderivative, so is $F+c$ for any constant $c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because a function is integrable, doesn't mean it has an antiderivative. Consider, for example, the function $f$ such that $f(0) = 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \ne 0$.

In this case, the derivative of $\int_c^x f(t) dt$ is not equal to $f(x)$ at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your misconception is typical: let us see if the following information can help you.
I don't use the symbol $[a,b]$ to simplify.

The point is to use *the function **is** a derivative* instead of *the function **has** an antiderivative*.

Not every derivative is Riemann integrable but (the FTC)

if a derivative $F'$ is Riemann integrable, then $$\int_a^b F'(x)\,dx=F(b)-F(a)$$

As for your calculus memories, there you meet only continuous derivatives and since every continuous function is Riemann integrable $\ldots$

Addendum: if you suspect vicious circles, note that Riemann integration is not the only way to prove that a function is a derivative (i.e. has an antiderivative): see my [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357135/priority-of-the-content-of-a-note-by-lebesgue-from-1905).